# Is is possible to use an ALSA card's channels independently and simultaneously?

Tags: linux, audio, raspberry-pi, alsa

I am trying to set up two zones on one sound card.  Each zone has a mono speaker which I would like to be able to play stereo downmixed to mono and to be able to play two different streams at once from two different processes.  So far I have a configuration like this in asound.conf

```
pcm.my_card {
type hw
card 1
}

pcm.my_card_dmix {
   type dmix
   ipc_key 1024
   ipc_key_add_uid 1
   ipc_perm 0666
   slave {
       pcm "my_card"
       channels 2
    }
    bindings {
       0 0
       1 1
    }
}

pcm.mono_zone1 {
type plug
slave.pcm my_card_dmix
slave.channels 2
ttable {
# Copy both input channels to output channel 0 (Left).
0.0 0.5
1.0 0.5
# Send nothing to output channel 1 (Right).
0.1 0
1.1 0
}
}

pcm.mono_zone2 {
type plug
slave.pcm my_card_dmix
slave.channels 2
ttable {
# Send nothing to output channel 0 (Left).
0.0 0
1.0 0
# Copy both input channels to output channel 1 (Right).
0.1 0.5
1.1 0.5
}
}
```

Unfortunately this does not work as I thought it would.  Sometimes, during playback, the streams going to mono_zone2 and the mono_zone1 will blend and come out of either or both zone speakers or they will switch places randomly and back again.  How can I configure it to isolate the two zones and allow two processes to those two zones independently?

Comment: This sounds like a hardware (driver) bug that has nothing to do with dmix. Does it happen with normal stereo files played to `my_card_dmix`?

Comment: that would be difficult for me to tell.  Having the right and left channels blend or swap when they belong to the same stereo stream (rather than two independent mono streams) could easily go unnoticed (and probably why this bug could go unnoticed, since I'm kind of doing an odd thing)

Comment: Combine two mono files (with `sox` or something like that), and try to play that.